# how to combine data in Python Dictionary

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a python dictionary like

```
my_list = [{'orderproduct_id': 76, 'orderproduct_quantity': '500', 'orderbatch_id': 'FOX19022019-2'}, 
           {'orderproduct_id': 76, 'orderproduct_quantity': '500', 'orderbatch_id': 'FOX19022019-1'}, 
           {'orderproduct_id': 77, 'orderproduct_quantity': '100', 'orderbatch_id': 'FOX19022019-1'}]
```

I want output like

```
my_list = [{'orderproduct_id': 76, 
            'batches': [{'orderproduct_quantity': '500', 'orderbatch_id': 'FOX19022019-2'}, 
                        {'orderproduct_quantity': '500', 'orderbatch_id': 'FOX19022019-1'}
                       ]
           }, 
           {'orderproduct_id': 77, 
            'batches': [{'orderproduct_quantity': '100', 'orderbatch_id': 'FOX19022019-1'}
                       ]
           }]
```

I am using that in Django view so if any Django function or python concept can work please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: You have to write some logic using for loop to achieve this

Comment: I tried some logic but it's not working. Can you please suggest me some logic?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried and where you stucked?

Comment: show your models with query. do you use `drf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the following! First of all, create a dictionary to keep as key the `orderproduct_id`, appending every `orderproduct_quantity` and `orderbatch_id` (both as a dictionary to a list). Then, just convert the dictionary to a list of dictionaries using a compression list, where the **key** will be the `orderproduct_id` and the **value**, the `batches`.

```py
output = {}
for p in my_list:
    id = p['orderproduct_id'] 
    if id not in output: # Create empty list for new IDs
        output[id] = []
    d = { 'orderproduct_quantity': p['orderproduct_quantity'],
          'orderbatch_id': p['orderbatch_id'] }
    output[id].append(d)

output = [{ 'orderproduct_id': k, 'batches': v } for k, v in output.items()]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use itertools:

```
from itertools import groupby

new_list = [ {'orderproduct_id': k, 'batches': list(i)}  
              for k, i in groupby(my_list, lambda x: x['orderproduct_id'])  ]
```

**Edited**

Edited to:

1. Sort list to use `groupby` safely.
2. Exclude key on inner list.

New code:

```
from itertools import groupby

my_key = lambda x: x['orderproduct_id']

[ {'orderproduct_id': k, 
   'batches': [ d for d in i if d.pop('orderproduct_id')  ]}  
  for k, i in groupby( sorted(my_list,key=my_key), my_key )  ]
```

**Explanation**

You are grouping by `orderproduct_id`. Then, the natural way is to use `groupby` function. When another developer see [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in few seconds he/she understand that the code is grouping elements.

Also, my approach uses [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) because you are creating new list/dictionaries from another iterables.

Comment: This requires that the input list to be sorted by `orderproduct_id` first, however.

Comment: Also you are including `orderproduct_id` inside the batches, which isn't a desired behaviour!

Comment: hi @blhsing, thanks about notice it to me! Fixed on answer.

Comment: hi @JosepJoestar , thanks about notice it to me! Fixed on answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can aggregate your items by `orderproduct_id` is separated dict:

```
aggregator = defaultdict(list)
for item in my_list:
    aggregator[item.pop('orderproduct_id')].append(item)
```

Then make a new list out of aggregated dict items:

```
new_list = []
for key, value in aggregator.items():
    new_list.append({
        'orderproduct_id': key,
        'batches': value
    })
```